# apt-get Could not connect to a weird IP/port, why?

Tags: apt

My apt-get for some reason, suddenly stopped to work properly and now I can't install any package whatsoever or do an update.. I have browsed and googled for some answers but nothing seems to work. At this point I am seriously considering resintalling Ubuntu to fix this.

What I have tried:

- Selecting the "Select Best Server" option from the Ubuntu Software Center. The speed was still drastically slow and unusable ultimately, because it just times out downloading and cancels between updates.
- Selecting the "Main Server". Same thing as before.
- Selecting the "Server for United States". Same thing as before.
- Generating a new sources.list from http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php. It didn't help the problem.
- Tried in different networks and there was no problem with the connection. The connection was fast and was downloading torrent for instance at 1 MByte/s speed.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

```
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                                                  
  Unable to connect to 213.181.73.145:8080:
```

and

```
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                                                          
  Could not connect to 213.181.73.145:8080 (213.181.73.145). - connect (110: Connection timed out)
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Also, I have tried with a similar computing power computer in the same network, with the same sources.list file, the same server, and on that computer the speed is 100x times faster and it works. Really confused about that as well!

Comment: I can't believe this. Yes, I was! I set it to be able to enter into some regional specific page and forgot to set it back, since I don't use Ubuntu as primary OS. Thank you so much! Now it's working as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely due you using a proxy, you can check using:

```
sudo apt-get -o Debug::Acquire::http=true update
```

This will give you more hindsight. You can check your configuration files for some proxy configured:

```
grep -i proxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/* /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

If none is found, check your Network Settings in the GUI and your environmental variables:

```
echo $http_proxy $HTTP_PROXY
```

Depending where you find it, you must unconfigure it. There could be also that the servers are down but since you changed server is difficult this happen.